# app pauses on launch at UIApplicationMain

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

Whenever I run my app, I see the splash screen shortly followed by the app pausing on the screen below. If i hit the play button a few times the app eventually runs. I don't believe anything is crashing nor does the app fail to behave as I'd expect, but I have no idea why this has been happening. This only appears when I have debugging enabled, but I don't see any breakpoints here so I don't know why it'd be stopping

Edit: I've noticed a lot of cxa throws and I set my 'All Exceptions' breakpoint to show only Objective-C. Still, anyone know why this would be happening?

[image]

Comment: `__cxa_throw` in the call stack would suggest it *is* crashing...